# AIR for iOS: 360° panorama viewer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, panoramas, 360-degrees

I'm working on an iOS application using AIR for iOS and am requested now to add support for 360° panorama images.

There are a few Flash panorama players available, but they create SWF files which I won't be able to compile into my iOS application (I assume?)

What options do I have to get interactive 360° panoramas into my AIR for iOS application?

//edit: the viewer should support spherical panoramas with proper distortion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean... can you not get the source code for these existing panoramas? If not, and you can just a SWF, then simply embed the SWF as a MovieClip class instance into your application and, to my knowledge, this should be just fine even on iOS.

Comment: I think you are correct. You can embed swf's in iOS. The limitation is on downloading external swf's. However I do not think it is possible to execute code inside an embedded swf on iOS

Comment: @f-a I think it would have to be tested cause I'm not 100% sure either. I would hope that the PFI compiler can intake the bytecode and convert appropriately for iOS, since that's essentially what it does for the actionscript you compile with ANTL3R and LLVM and the GlobalOptimizer class in the ACS.jar. But you never know... this is Adobe after all.

Comment: IIRC it's not an Adobe limitation as the issue does not exist on Android. It's a limitation implemented by Apple on iOS.

Comment: Even if you could, it might not be performant enough. A lot of the desktop targeted panoramic viewers are a little sloppy on their memory management which can demolish performance on an iOS or android device. I *have* written AS3/AIR based panoramic viewers for mobile devices, its *definitely* possible but you have to be careful of the constraints.

Comment: @f-a I wasn't talking about the restriction of having swfs I was making a jab at Adobe having an incomplete compiler implementation. I was basically saying that while you should expect this feature, you can't exactly rely on Adobe to have done it.

Comment: @AscensionSystems Fair enough :)

Comment: I just tried JCPanoramaViewer. It comes as an Flash component, which I exported into an SWC and used in my AIR project. It runs fine in the iPad simulator of flashbuilder, but it does not show up on the device. I assume that JCPanoramaViewer uses PixelBender for the pserspectivic distortion. Does anyone know of a flash panoramaviewer that does not rely on PixelBender?

Comment: @Mat I'm pretty sure that JCPano doesn't use PixelBenders. It looks like a fairly standard panoramic implementation in as3 using `Graphics.drawTriangles()`. I would look for and external swf's that its trying load -- which aren't allowed on iOS -- or missing resources (like the configuration xml) when it got deployed to the device.

Comment: @32bitkid - you're absolutely right! after checking it, there was something wrong with the paths - it does render on the iPad and is even on iPad1 performant enough :)